# How do I compare oldVal with newVal in the $scope.$watch method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have defined a modal window in which the user selects a different value then what was selected before. The modal window should preserve this value after it has been closed. I've tried to implement this using the `$scope.$watch` method but it does not seem to be working. I've defined the controller below:

Ctrl.js

```
$scope.openEpcfTreeModel = function() {
  $scope.$watch('nonPersistentProcess.requestedEpcfKey', function(oldVal,newVal){
    var oldEpcf = oldVal;
    console.log("oldEpcf",oldEpcf);
    console.log("newVal",newVal);
    if(newVal !== oldVal) {
          $scope.nonPersistentProcess.requestedEpcfKey = oldVal;
    }
  });
}
```

How do I fix the bug in my code?

Comment: I don't understand what your should do? When 'nonPersistentProcess.requestedEpcfKey' changed, you reset the value to its old value. Why? Second what is the value type of 'oldVal' and 'newVal'. When it is an object, maybe they don't point to the same object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct function signature for [$scope.watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) is:

```
$scope.watch('nonPersistentProcess.requestedEpcfKey', function(newVal, oldVal) {
  // Rest of the code.
});
```

`newVal` comes before `oldVal` in the parameter list.

Comment: thanks i will fix that but it does not solve my actual problem